# Eclipse doesn't work after update

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04, adt

In eclipse all functionality missed. There are only 5 tabs left in properties:
General,
Help,
Install/Update,
Run/Debug,
Team.
And Eclipse opens all *.java and *.xml files as txt(without highlight)

I'm new in Eclipse and it can be something simple.
But I think it happened because of one of plugins. I don't know how to check it. Before it happened I updated Android plugin and restarted. I don't remember, may be i updated something else too.

Ubuntu 12.04,
Eclipse 3.7.2

Comment: First, your question have a lot of missing information (figured English isn't your primary language). Second, in my opinion, Eclipse is not designed for beginner. They have many flavour and many plug-ins which often don't just work when you install them. Many dependancies needs to be fixed. So hard to help with the limited information here.

Comment: I think, Eclipse is best choice for beginners. I have used it about month, and it is first time, when it broken so hard. What information should I add?

Comment: Delete Eclipse, and restore Eclipse from the zip file.  Add one plug-in at a time, and zip Eclipse after each successful plug-in added. When all of the plug-ins are added, zip up eclipse so you can restore it when it gets corrupted again.

Comment: Yes it is the best solution for newbies. I already do it =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this first: start Eclipse with the -clean command line argument, which will clear out cached plugin information. Startup will take longer, but you have to do this only once.

If that doesn't help, go to Help/About. Click on the Installation Details button. The window that pops up has an "Installation History" button, where you can see what changed. You can also revert the changes back out.

Comment: I tried to revert but eclipse couldn't download some files. Ultimately I re-installed Eclipse. The fastest option. I wanted to understand what the problem was, but it could take a lot of time.